# Integrate jstree and select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jstree, jquery-select2-4

In my page I use `jstree` and `select2`. I would like to have both plug-ins integrated. Is there any way? My code looks very simple, because it relies only on the fields of integration of plug-ins and it looks like:

```
var dataSelect = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "test"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "test2"
    },
    {
        id: 3, text: "test3"
    }
];

var dataTree = [
    {
        id: 1, text: "test"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "test3"
    }
];

    $('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': dataTree,
        "themes": {
            "icons": false
        }
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false,
        "three_state": true
    },
    "plugins": ["checkbox", "state"]
});

$("#selectSample").select2({
    data: dataSelect,
    multiple: true
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1188/)

As you can see, data in both cases have similar a ID. If I click `test` in my tree, then I would want my `select` set to `"test"`. Is there any solution for this problem?

**EDIT**

@Nikolay Ermakov answer led me to correct thinking, but the problem is when I load my `select` by ajax. When I click some option in my jstree, the data is destroyed and I cannot choose anything later in my `select`. In addition, none of the options is selected on `select2`.

**EDIT2**

When I click some option in `jstree`, all options are removed, and to `select` goes one blank value, which can be selected.

Comment: chcek for the `select_node.jstree` event

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1189/ ok, I made something like this, but why this return only one option?

Comment: OK, I put the data in array and handed it to select, everything works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I made your interaction two-way. Please check this fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/3kgbG/1195/).

I used `changed` event of jsTree and `select/unselect` events of select2.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
var dataSelect = [{id: "1", text: "test"},{id:"2", text: "test2"},{id:"3", text: "test3"}];
var dataTree = [{id: "1", text: "test"},{id:"3", text: "test3"}];


$("#selectSample").select2({data:dataSelect, multiple: true});

$('#jstree')
    .on('changed.jstree', function (event, data) {
        var $select = $("#selectSample").select2(),
            selectedOptions = $select.val() || [],
            optionId = data.node.id;

        if( data.action == 'select_node'){ 
          selectedOptions.push( optionId );
          $select.val(selectedOptions).trigger("change");
        }

        if( data.action == 'deselect_node'){ 
          selectedOptions.splice( selectedOptions.indexOf( optionId ), 1 );
          $select.val(selectedOptions).trigger("change");
        }

    })
    .jstree({
        'core': {
          'data': dataTree,
          "themes":{
            "icons":false
          }
        },
        "checkbox": {
          "keep_selected_style": false,
          "three_state": true
        },
        "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
    });

$("#selectSample")
    .on('select2:select', function(event) {
      $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', '#'+event.params.data.id, true);
    })
    .on('select2:unselect', function(event) {
      $('#jstree').jstree('deselect_node', '#'+event.params.data.id, true);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, looks good, but when I copy this solution to my portal I have one problem - "data.node is undefined".

Comment: Ok, I located the problem. It depends on the data to select2 loading via ajax. When the jstree wants to add the selected option on its just not see it. Is there any way around this? I would add that the loading of data through ajax is required.

Comment: Can you look up what value you have in `optionId` variable in jsTree when you select a node and the `onchange` event is fired? Also what data you get as a result of this action after fetching ajax: `processResults: function (data, page) { return { results: $.map(data, function(obj) { return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text, val: obj.val }; }) }; }` - what the output here looks like?

Comment: Can you do what I suggested above: look up what value you have in `optionId` variable in jsTree when you select a node and the onchange event is fired? Also what data you get as a result of this action after fetching ajax: `processResults: function (data, page) { return { results: $.map(data, function(obj) { return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text, val: obj.val }; }) }; }` - what the output here looks like?

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. When I select some option in jstree i have "id, text, icon, parent, parents, children, selected etc. in optionID Same options show when I unselected option. Ajax give me JSON type with parameters: id, text and val.

Comment: It seems like you may have written `optionId = data.node;` instead of `optionId = data.node.id;` in the beginning of the `changed.jstree` event handler for jsTree. Please check this because the `optionId` variable is supposed to contain only a simple value (of `id`) and not the object as it comes out your reply.

Comment: I did like you said, continue the same. Above the second edition of main post I described problem. If I click some option in jstree my select dont load data from ajax and i can selected only one, blank option :/

Comment: Quite weird behavior. You should show more of your code relevant to jsTree and Select interaction, maybe copy it into you original question. However I think you are very close to solving your problem.

Comment: I have basically nothing more code, but also load data by AJAX to Jstree. The rest of the code I use of your solution

Answer (score 0):

something like this worked -

```
var dataSelect = [{id: 1, text: "test"},{id:2, text: "test2"},{id:3, text: "test3"}];
var dataTree = [{id:1, text: "test"},{id:3, text: "test3"}];

$('#jstree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': dataTree,
            "themes":{
            "icons":false
        }
        },
            "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false,
            "three_state": true
        },
            "plugins" : [ "checkbox","state" ]
    })
.on("select_node.jstree", function(a,b){
  $("#selectSample").append('<option value="' + b.node.original.text + '">' + b.node.original.text + '</option>');
  var selectedValues = $("#selectSample").val();
  if (selectedValues == null) {
        selectedValues = new Array();
     }
  selectedValues.push(b.node.original.text);
  $("#selectSample").val(selectedValues).trigger('change');
});

$("#selectSample").select2({data:dataSelect, multiple: true});
```

Comment: Yeah, looks great, but sometimes add too many objects. 
The situation is when I delete all checked boxes, then again I might add field.

Comment: Yet another problem why when exchange 'b.node.original.text' to 'b.node.original.id' in value option field will not be added?

Comment: `b.node.original` is the object exposed by this event. Inspect to see if it has an `Id` or some other property associated that you find helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will change this and my code looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1193/

but it's not the end of it properly and do not know why: /

Comment: Can you please try opening a web app and debug to find what properties the object expose and which one suits you(if any)

Comment: Also you can listen to `deselect_node.jstree Event` to empty the array .

Comment: Hmm as You can see, the option was deleted from select2 (not hide), and when I select some option sometimes add two times and I dont know why :/

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I solved my problem! :) 
 I used the solution sent by @Nikolay Ermakov. However, my initiating a select was a little wrong. Using the $ .ajax () reads an argument and I gave it to my select later. So the generated code works fine! :) Thank you all for your commitment! :)